# Paged UICollectionView расстояние между полноэкранными UICollectionViewCell только при скролле

Tags: uicollectionview, objective-c, swift, ios, xcode

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос в следующем: как добавить расстояние между элементами в фото галлерее только при прокрутке, при этом сами картинки должны быть полноэкранными, а collectionView.pagingEnabled = true?

Comment: а это не оно?
<pre>
– startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion:
– finishInteractiveTransition
– cancelInteractiveTransition
<code>

Comment: можно еще параллакс влепить, оно красивее, но ресурс жрет немного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал просто - делать UICollectionView шире чем экран на 4 пикселя.
А контент на каждой страничке делал уже на 5 пикселя (и как раз получается fullScreen) но при листании видны разрывы. Грязно, конечно, но работает :)
Если найдете другой способ - напишите потом сюда.

Comment: У вас не выводится в логи всякое типа того, что размер ячейки неверный и все такое? Потому что ячейка больше экрана?

Comment: Нет, я использовал FlowLayout